# Python not treating all input files equal?

Tags: python, csv

I have this code:

```
import csv, itertools

with open("test.csv") as f:
    with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f2:
    # with open("output.csv","wb") as f2:   # uncomment for python 2 (comment above!)

        cw = csv.writer(f2,delimiter=";")
        for l in itertools.groupby((l.split() for l in f),lambda x : x[0]):
            grouped = set(x[1] for x in l[1])  # set avoids duplicate rows
            if len(grouped)>1:
                for c in itertools.combinations(grouped,2):
                    cw.writerow(c)
```

It used to work to read files formatted as:

```
1     abc
1     def
2     ghi
3     jkl
3     mno
3     pqr
```

And output them as:

```
abc;def
jkl;mno
jkl;pqr
mno;pqr
```

But it does not work now when I am reusing the code. Using [this input file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/834z13dgnapukdu/test.csv?dl=0), it results in an empty output.csv.

Comment: have you tried that code with the file you claim it works with? I think the line `cw.writerow` is missing the part where you **call the method.**

Comment: Sorry, The `cw.writerow` is supposed to be followed by `(c)`. I have edited it now. Still does not work.

Comment: The reuse of `l` in the nested for loops is a problem.

Comment: Needs to be `l` in all of those places for the code not to throw errors.